# Laravel | Axios | Get function | 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, get, axios

Im trying to get data from my database table named : `Experiences`.

And then I got a `500 Internal Server` error .. But I can't find where I missed.

My code is below

**My index page**

[image: In my index page i wrote :]

**GetExperiences**

[image: in my controller i wrote about the function GetExperiences]

**My Route**

[image: My Route]

**Error message**

[image: Error Message in my console]

Comment: And contents of `/getexperiences`? There the error is explained in details...

Comment: Maybe check your `Experience`  model along with contents `CvController`.

Comment: Open the console and after you get the 500 error go to your network tab, click on the error and then click on preview. You should then be able to see the error message.